# The Broadcast Receiver didn't start after starting the activity class

Tags: android, sqlite, service, broadcastreceiver

I am assigned a project on vehicle tracking system to be developed as an android app.

Project Brief:
A vehicle driver is been given a GPRS powered android OS installed phone so that the location is tracked. The assumption is that all route coordinates (latitude & longitude) are already stored in DB.Such that when the driver crosses a particular place, there should be an alert (change of status) in the DB.In this way, the tracking shall be made efficiently.

My Issue:
I have developed the program but unable to get it executed. I am wondering if my coding is totally wrong or I had left something in between. I have attached/pasted the program for your consideration.

I shall be too glad to receive inputs from you & see the dawn of the project's execution.
You shall reach me at inbasharu@gmail.com
Alternately, if you are magnanimous in helping me outright do buzz me @ 9659709092/7305738685

My codes are:

1.proximity Alert Receiver

```
public class ProximityAlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTIVE_TASK_LOC = "com.android.model.TaskLoc";
    private static final String ACTIVE_TASK_TEXT = "com.android.model.TaskText";
    private static final String ACTIVE_TASK_USER_ID = "com.android.model.TaskUserid";
    private static final String ACTIVE_TASK_ROUTE_NUM = "com.android.model.TaskRoutenum";
    private static final String ACTIVE_TASK_TOWARDS = "com.android.model.TaskTowards";
    Ringtone r;

    private static String url_create = "";
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    int id;
    String taskLoc, taskText, taskRoutenum, taskUserid, taskTowards;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {

            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    LocationProxyService.class.getName());
            ComponentName service = context.startService(new Intent()
                    .setComponent(comp));

            if (null == service) {
            } else {

            }
        } else {

            String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
            Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            taskLoc = bundle.getString(ACTIVE_TASK_LOC);
            String taskText = bundle.getString(ACTIVE_TASK_TEXT);
            String taskRoutenum = bundle.getString(ACTIVE_TASK_VEHICLE_NUM);
            String taskUserid = bundle.getString(ACTIVE_TASK_USER_ID);
            String taskTowards = bundle.getString(ACTIVE_TASK_TOWARDS);

            if (entering) {
                try {
                    enterLocation(context, "Task : \"" + taskText + "\"",
                            "You are Near to  " + taskLoc, "UserId : \""
                                    + taskUserid + "\"", "Vehicle_no : \""
                                    + taskRoutenum + "\"", "Towrads : \""
                                    + taskTowards);
                    enterLocation(context, "Task : \"" + taskText + "\"",
                            "You are Near to  " + taskLoc, "UserId : \""
                                    + taskUserid + "\"", "Vehicle_no : \""
                                    + taskRoutenum + "\"", "Towrads : \""
                                    + taskTowards);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            } else {

                exitLocation(context, "Task : \"" + taskText + "\"",
                        "You are Leaving " + taskLoc + " already!");
            }

        }
    }

    public void enterLocation(Context context, String contentText,
            String contentTitle, String contentUserid, String contentVehicle_no,
            String contentTowards) {

          Toast.makeText(context, contentText + "" + contentTitle,
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          Intent service = new Intent(context, set_routes.class);
            context.startService(service);

            new Ajax().execute();

    }

    public void exitLocation(Context context, String contentText,
            String contentTitle) {
        Toast.makeText(context, contentText + "" + contentTitle,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    class Ajax extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {// JSON STARTS HERE

        // new CreateNewProduct().execute();

        protected ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters;
        protected String v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11;
        boolean success;
        String msg = "";

        public Ajax() {
            super();
            v1 = taskUserid;
            v2 = taskRoutenum;
            v3 = taskLoc;
            v4 = taskTowards;

            parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            NameValuePair name = new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", v1);
            NameValuePair mobile_no = new BasicNameValuePair("Vehicle_no", v2);
            NameValuePair email = new BasicNameValuePair("current_stop", v3);
            NameValuePair password = new BasicNameValuePair("towards", v4);
            // NameValuePair address = new BasicNameValuePair("address", v9);

            parameters.add(name);
            parameters.add(mobile_no);
            parameters.add(email);
            parameters.add(password);
            // parameters.add(address);
            success = false;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            /*
             * pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Newproduct.this);
             * pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
             * pDialog.setIndeterminate(false); pDialog.setCancelable(true);
             * pDialog.show();
             */
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create, "POST",
                    this.parameters);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", "asdf" + json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                success = json.getBoolean(TAG_SUCCESS);
                msg = json.getString("message");
                if (success) {
                    id = json.getInt("id");

                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            if (success) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sucessfully inserted" + id,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), set_vehicles.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }

        private Context getBaseContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        private Context getApplicationContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        private void startActivity(Intent i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please give more details? Is the problem that activity is not started at the OnPostExectute?

Comment: i am not getting a problem any where